# FBJS setStyle( {backgroundImage}) not working?

Tags: javascript, fbml, fbjs

i am trying to add some images to my facebook tab-app via FBJS.

**The Problem:**
I can't see the images and I don't know why.

**The FBJS code**

```
url = "http://www.domain.de/image.gif";
myImg = document.createElement('img');
myImg.setStyle( {backgroundImage: 'url('+url+')' });
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(myImg);
```

**The rendered html**

```
<img style="background-image: url("http://www.domain.de/image.gif";);">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your code like this and specify the `src` attribute of the image:

```
url = "http://www.domain.de/image.gif";
myImg = document.createElement('img');
myImg.setSrc(url);
document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(myImg);
```

Comment: This is FBJS (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs), not pure JavaScript+DOM. (And if it were, no need for `setAttribute`, `src` is a reflected attribute.) **And** he's setting a background image, though that seems weird.

Comment: @fabian: Exactly, it is `setSrc`; sorry i forgot, it has been quite some time since i did facebook app development :)

Answer (score 0):

You're really thing to set the background image of an `img` element? That seems...odd. Are you sure you don't just want to do a normal `img` element (Sarfraz may have you covered there if so) or specify the background image of the wrapper element? E.g.:

```
url = "http://www.domain.de/image.gif";
document.getElementById('wrapper').setStyle( {backgroundImage: 'url('+url+')' });
```

I've marked this CW because I've never done any FBJS, so could be talking through my hat. :-) If it helps, it helps.